# Override native js function in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, overriding

In IE 11 doesnt work the native function override like this:

```
var toEval='function myClose(){'+
    '  alert(88)'+
    '}'+
    'window.close=myClose;'
eval(toEval)
```

Someone has some ideas ??
Thanks

Comment: Why in heaven's name would you want to do that? Instead of *not* putting the code in a string and `eval`ing it (e.g., just put the code in properly).

Comment: I copied from our context..but it doesn't work also witout eval

Answer (score 0):

Browser will NOT allow to override the global close function.

However, if you want to execute some code before window is closed you can use the *onbeforeunload* event.

To display a confirmation dialog to the user, return a string value from the event handler as shown below.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   var ans = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
   if(!ans){
      return "confirmation";
   }
};
```